# Removing part of a string in BigQuery based on a condition to remove duplicates

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to remove parts of a string that don’t overlap with a string in another row. I have a table that looks like this

| customer_number | customer_name | product_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | John Doe | product name 1 |
| 1234 | John Doe | product name 2 |

What I’m trying to do is remove the numbers (in the example case) from the product name and combine these two rows into on so that it would look like this:

| customer_number | customer_name | product_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | John Doe | product name |

I think I need to use coalesce and then regexp, but I’m not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following distinct query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    customer_number,
    customer_name,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(product_name, r'\s+\w+$', '') AS product_name
FROM yourTable;
```

The call being made above to `REGEXP_REPLACE()` is stripping off the trailing ending word in the product name.

Comment: but if the values are not numbers this would fail

Comment: Unfortunately the values are not numbers, is there any way to change this so it would work with words? Let’s say “product name one”, “product name two” instead of “product name 1”, “product name 2”

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all the `product_name` with same `customer_number` has common prefix, you might consider below.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT '1234' customer_number, 'John Doe' customer_name, 'product name 2' product_name UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234' customer_number, 'John Doe' customer_name, 'product name 1 a' product_name UNION ALL
  SELECT '1234' customer_number, 'John Doe' customer_name, 'product name 1 b' product_name
)
SELECT customer_number, customer_name,
       (SELECT STRING_AGG(w, ' ') 
          FROM UNNEST (SPLIT(product_name, ' ')) w WITH offset o1
          JOIN UNNEST (SPLIT(anchor, ' ')) a WITH offset o2
            ON w = a AND o1 = o2
       ) AS product_name
  FROM (
    SELECT *, FIRST_VALUE(product_name) OVER w0 AS anchor
      FROM sample_table
    WINDOW w0 AS (PARTITION BY customer_number, customer_name ORDER BY LENGTH(product_name))
  ) AS t QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER w1 = 1
WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY customer_number, customer_name ORDER BY LENGTH(product_name));
```

**Query results**

[image]